# Creating a bucket responds with 'bucket exists'

Tags: autodesk-forge

When attempting to create a transient bucket, many of the bucket names I set result in failing to create the bucket, with the response set to: "reason": "Bucket already exists"

So when I try say 'buckettest' and 'buckettest2', which I know I've never created before, I still get "Bucket already exists". Only when I try and obscure bucket name does it work eg "DMT123"

I am posting to: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets
{
      "bucketKey":"buckettest",
      "policyKey":"transient"
    }

Answer (score 1):

from: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/forge-3ds-max-create-bucket.html

`bucket_name="nh"+uuid.uuid4().hex+"test1" # must be globally unique!!!`

the bucket names in Autodesk Forge must be globally unique. The ones you are using are not globally unique.

Answer (score 0):

See official documentation [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/#body-structure):

> bucketKey*
>   string
>   A unique name you assign to a bucket. It must be globally unique across all applications and
>   regions, otherwise the call will fail. Possible values: -_.a-z0-9 (between 3-128 characters in
>   length). Note that you cannot change a bucket key.

And refer to code sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs/routes/oss.js#L79) to automatically append prefix to the bucket names and create globally unique buckets.